# New Map Object is hidden

Tags: reactjs

I am mapping of array of object which multiplies my component, its working properly but the problem is when I add another object to it somehow its hidden not sure why

```
{EditMultiObject.map((object, key) => (
            <SubFormEditCom
              key={key}
              identifyNumber={key}
              onEditBasicChange={onEditBasicChange}
              onEditCalendarChange={onEditCalendarChange}
              onEditChangeUrl={onEditChangeUrl}
              lastObject={EditMultiObject.length === key + 1 ? true : false}
              onEditAddNewObject={onEditAddNewObject}
            />
          ))}
```

You will noticed the first element is the initial object I set the second is the one I created when I click a add button. The style on the second div is missing(the newly added one) an inline style, note that I didnt even put an inline style in my code I assume it was added by react

[image]

Comment: Nothing in code shown is related to style or any of the classes shown.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know now whats the solution for this I think its because of the third party library